# Most efficient practice for &$key and &$value references in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

Is it's better/more performant to use a &$key and &$value reference here instead of $payload[$key]... then destroy the references using unset after foreach loop?

Or is the way I have it, fine for a best practice?... If not, please give an example:

```
foreach ($payload as $key => $value) {
  if (is_array($value)) {
    $payload[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, implode(',', $value));
  } else {
    $payload[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, $value);
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter. even if there is some performance impact, it's insignificant. And I don't think keys can be referenced

Comment: It's more efficient to use prepared statements than the dated manual escaping. Use a profiler for the rest, not guesses.

Comment: Readability trumps performance in such minuscule differences every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So performance usually falls into three categories - CPU, memory or i/o. In your case we are talking about the memory.

If you desperately need to save memory, use references (&$value) instead of copy-by-value instances. However I often find this to be a premature optimization. Consider for how long is this value going to be in the memory: how many users even hit upon this given function? what is the scope of the function? etc.

So worry more about maintenance -- making the code understandable to the next person or yourself in three months -- than couple of kilobytes you could be saving.

Additional note: in this case, using references (`&$value`) would save memory because you're changing `$value`. But if all you're doing is reading a value, then it truly doesn't matter at all...for a while now, PHP's default behavior (i.e. when you don't use &) is to actually copy arrays by reference until you change them, at which point it copies them first.

Comment: I edited it and deleted my comment. Thanks for pointing that out.